# MongoDB read-only user not authenticating

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I'm currently attempting to create a read-only user in MongoDB for a grader. The MongoDB instance is hosted remotely on AWS EC2, and the security groups are all set up properly.

I can SSH onto the remote machine and authenticate with the read-only account there, like so:

```
# On remote machine
mongo -u <read-only username> -p <read-only-pwd> <database>
```

However, as soon as I try to connect to that same instance from my local machine using `mongo`, I encounter authentication errors.

```
# On local machine
mongo -u <read-only username> -p <read-only pwd> <host>/<database>
```

What gives?

The read-only user exists on `<database>`, and has `"read"` permissions.

Comment: When you say encounter authentication errors what do you mean? Please provide error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not trying to authenticate with the wrong machine.

I'm an idiot.